# Entity Framework - Save ICollection of Enumeration in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, enums

I have a class with a property of type `ICollection<Enum>`.

Say for example we have the following `enumeration`:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
    VIP,
    FrequentCustomer,
    BadCustomer
}
```

We also have the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get;set; } 
    public string FirstName { get;set; } 
    public string LastName { get;set; } 
    public ICollection<CustomerType> CustomerAtrributes { get;set; }
}
```

How can I store the property `CustomerAtrributes` in the database to be easily retrieved later?

For example I'm looking for something like the following:

```
CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | CustomerType    |  
1          | Bob       | Smith    | VIP             |  
1          | Bob       | Smith    | FrequentCustomer|  
2          | Mike      | Jordan   | BadCustomer     |
```

EDIT: I'm using EntityFramework 6 to store my objects in the database using the CodeFirst approach.

EDIT: A friend found a possible duplicate : [ef 5 codefirst enum collection not generated in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045303/ef-5-codefirst-enum-collection-not-generated-in-database) .But please, if you have any different ideas or workarounds, post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum is still a primitive type, in particular an integer. Just as your `Costumer` class can't have an `ICollection<int>` that maps to something in the database, it can't have a collection of the enum.

You have to create a CostumerType class and rename the enum:

```
public enum TypesOfCostumer //example name
{
    VIP,
    FrequentCustomer,
    BadCustomer
}

public class CostumerType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TypesOfCostumer Type {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the property is not saved at all. I don't really mind if it is a string or an integer. I used a string just for presentation purposes

Comment: did you run the migrations? Your model seems fine to me

Comment: Yeah, and it completely ignored my property :'(

Comment: Yeah, I edited my post with an answer I found that is similar to yours. Thanks for the reply though. I'm going to accept your answer as it seems it is the only decent solution to this problem.