# Seed Entity Framework Model with List Member

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework model with a list member:

```
public class MyModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Feature` is an enum.

I have a `Seed()` method in my configuration with an object literal:

```
new MyModel
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test Name",
    Points = 2,
    Features = ???
}
```

How can I initialize Features as a literal list?

Comment: Seeing the answers (so far) nobody seems to notice that you can't store a `List<Feature>` in the database. Think of it, which data type should the target database field have? `Feature` must be a class, mapped to its own table.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32072732/861716

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold - complete amateur hour for me, forgetting about `enum`s with Entity Framework. I've updated my answer below, which should now solve OP's question :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I initialize Features as a literal list?

**UPDATE**
As quite rightly pointed out by @Gert, you cannot use enums directly in an EF database *(Oh, drats)*.

However, an `enum` is represented by an `int`, so the value can still be stored in the database, by the use of a class.

You will need to create a class in order to store the values in the database, and then you are able to refer to it from the `MyModel` class.

Like this:

```
public enum TypesOfFeature // The enum of features
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
    ... // etc.
}

public class Feature // The class to map to a table in your DB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TypesOfFeature Type { get; set; }
}
```

Add a `DbSet<Feature>` to your code-first model, so you can access this from your DB. Something like `public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }` will do.

It might be a good idea to manually add the values into the database so you know their IDs will match the enum's `int` value. *You *could* do this using `AddOrUpdate` in the`Seed()` method - then when you need to add more, you could add them beneath*

You would need to return the `Feature`s you want, from the DB in order to then assign them to your `MyModel.Features` property.

Like so:

```
Feature featureOne = YourDbContext.Features.Single(x => x.Type == TypesOfFeature.One);
Feature featureTwo = YourDbContext.Features.Single(x => x.Type == TypesOfFeature.Two);
Feature featureThree = YourDbContext.Features.Single(x => x.Type == TypesOfFeature.Three);
```

Then, in the code, where you're initializing your `MyModel` object, you can then initialize the `List<Feature>`, passing in the required `Feature` objects you pulled out above:

```
var model = new MyModel
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test Name",
    Points = 2,
    Features = new List<Feature>
               {
                   featureOne,
                   featureTwo,
                   featureThree
                }
}
```

Obviously, I don't know what values you have in your `Feature` `enum`, but above is just an example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How can I use `Feature` in the `MyModel` seeds? I add `Feature` objects in the seed by using  `context.Features.AddOrUpdate`. I then do `context.SaveChanges()` followed by `context.MyModel.AddOrUpdate` which I pass a `new MyModel { ..., Features = new List<Feature> { context.Features.Single(x => x.Type == TypesOfFeature.One) } }`. The problem is that when I grab `MyModel` objects from `context` they have an empty `Features` list.

Comment: Where exactly is it you are trying to use `MyModel.Features` and get this problem? And what type of program are you writing (App, MVC etc.)? Are the `Features` empty or `null`?

Comment: I have a console application which I added the entity framework to. From my main method I create a context and get an object by doing `var firstMyModel = context.MyModel.First()` the problem is that `firstMyModel.Features` is `null`

Comment: Have you found this via the debugger or the output from the console window? Off the top of my head (I'm on mobile so a bit limited for space): You might want to declare your `Features` as a navigation property. A quick Google will show you this. I might suggest researching into Lazy Loading/Eager Loading in EF and how you can use it. You could also use Explicit Loading. As an example: where you do your query to select `MyModel` objects, use `context.MyModels.Include(x => x.Features)` where you grab them from the DB. You will need to include `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it as list of enum

```
 var model = new MyModel
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Test Name",
            Points = 2,
            Features = new List<Feature>
            {
                Feature.Feature1,
                Feature.Feature2
            }
        };
```

Comment: Wrong. `List<Feature>` can't be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyModel mm = new MyModel();

        mm.Id = 1;
        mm.Name = "user3728304";
        mm.Points = 1;
        mm.Features = new List<Feature>{Feature.one,
                         Feature.two,
                         Feature.three};

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Wrong. `List<Feature>` can't be stored in the database.

Comment: @GertArnold You can store it in different table, say Model_Feature bu using model id and Feature, one to many relation b\w model and Feature.

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't.